Cross reference to included plantuml
I want to write a documentation with asciidoc, including a plantuml. This is how I do :
[plantuml, title="My great title"]
----
[[sch_id]]
include::plantuml_sources/my_source.pu[]
----

And I want to add a cross reference to this schema in my file. I wrote this :
some text ... (see <<sch_id>>)

It works but text contains see [sch_id], how can I do to display schema's title instead of id ?

You can set "reftext" for the id, then internal cross-references automatically use the reftext as the link label:
[#sch_id, reftext="My schema diagram"]
[plantuml, title="My great title"]
----
include::plantuml_sources/my_source.pu[]
----

Note: I moved the id out of the code block, updated to use the more modern syntax, and applied the reftext attribute.

That's exactly what I wanted, thanks. I'll search information about the modern syntax.
